# Problems with installing Nvidia Graphics Driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

I have a Nvidia Graphics 1050 ti card.
I wanted to install the drivers for the Graphics card so I followed a tutorial and did the following.

I have disabled nouveau to istall nvidia driver by using nano to create a file in **modprobe.d** called ***blacklist.nouveau.conf*** and wrote

blacklist nouveau

options nouveau modeset=0

Then I rebooted my computer
and used *chmod +x* to run the driver

It gave me this error.

[Click Here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1UBh.png)

I have searched everywhere and got tired can someone please help me?

Comment: In your error report, there was a reference to `/etc/modeprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf`. Also, please edit your question and post the output of the command: `cat /etc/modeprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf`

Comment: What you followed is a lousy tutorial. In Ubuntu is as easy as opening "additional drivers", selecting and applying the recommended version and then reboot. Do not use the file downloaded from Nvidia. Proper and tested drivers are already available in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: GabrielaGarcia how do I do it

Comment: Nvm I got it. Ubuntu is better than windows